# Cannot get the position the GameObject where the script is attach

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem when i'm referencing the game Object :

Wolf is a class where pos is a Public vector3 and the error occur at wolf.pos = this.transform.position;

Here the code:

```
 public class Hunter : MonoBehaviour {

 Wolf wolf;
 SpawnSheep meat;
 public GameObject hunter;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {
     meat = FindObjectOfType<SpawnSheep>();
     wolf.pos = this.transform.position;
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {
     wolf.pos = this.transform.position;
     for (int x = 0; x < meat.sheeps.Length; x++)
     {
         Debug.DrawLine(wolf.pos, meat.sheeps[x].pos, Color.red);
     }  
 }
```

What did i do wrong? Is "this" not allowed in unity ? thanks in advance

Comment: You haven't initialized `Wolf` --- `wolf = new Wolf();` or something else if you want to inherits it from somewhere.

Comment: Worth noting that in Unity if `Wolf` inherits from GameObject, you don't want to initialize it with the `new` keyword. But @AleksaRistic makes a good point otherwise - where do you assign a value to `wolf`, such that you can access the instance's `pos` member?

Comment: @Serlite yap, that is what i wanted to tell him. He hasn't assigned any object to `Wolf wolf` class so when he try `wolf.pos` since `wolf == null` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the `wolf` variable. If the `Wolf` class is a monobehavior, you cannot arbitrarily create a new instance. If the `wolf` variable is intended to be set through the inspector on the prefab, make it a `public` or `[System.Serializable]` field and set the reference in the `Hunter`'s inspector. Otherwise, you need some way to create the wolf

- `wolf = GameObject.Instantiate<Wolf>(WolfPrefab)`
- Get the reference: `wolf = FindObjectOfType<Wolf>()` (not recommended for
  performance reasons)
- Pass it from another function.